# How to send email with invoice programatically in Magento2?

Tags: magento2, invoice, send-mail

In my custom module I want to send email with invoice to another email.
I have created the following script

```
<?php
namespace My\CustomScripts\Cron;

class SendInvoice
{

    protected $_invoiceSender;

    protected $_invoice;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\InvoiceSender $invoiceSender,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Invoice $invoice
    )
    {
        $this->_invoiceSender = $invoiceSender;
        $this->_invoice = $invoice;
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $invoice_id = '000000025';
        $invoiceData = $this->_invoice->loadByIncrementId($invoice_id);
        $this->_invoiceSender->send($invoiceData, true);

        return $this;
    }

}
```

inresult i resievd en error:
Warning: DOMDocument::schemaValidate(): Invalid Schema in /var/www/html/projecttest/vendor/magento/framework/Config/Dom.php on line 311

What is wrong ?

Comment: Seem that it relates to xml validation.